# Conditions any dense embedding from $(0,1]$ into $[0,1]$ must satisfy

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

This is a proof-verification request. Suppose that $m:(0,1]\to[0,1]$ is a dense embedding. That is,

- $m$ is continuous;
- $m$ is injective;
- the image $m\big((0,1]\big)$ is dense in $[0,1]$;
- $m$ has a continuous inverse from its image $m\big((0,1]\big)$ onto its domain $(0,1]$.

Throughout, $(0,1]$ and $[0,1]$ are endowed with the usual topologies.

$\textbf{Claim:}\phantom{---}$Either one of the following two cases must hold:

(1) $m$ is strictly increasing, $m(1)=1$, and $\lim_{x\downarrow0}m(x)=0$; or

(2) $m$ is strictly decreasing, $m(1)=0$, and $\lim_{x\downarrow0}m(x)=1$.

$\textit{Proof sketch:}\phantom{---}$Since $m$ is continuous and injective on a connected subinterval of $\mathbb R$, it [must be strictly monotone](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Injection_of_Interval_is_Strictly_Monotone). In both cases, the other two endpoint conditions are implied by the fact that the image of $m$ is dense in $[0,1]$. $\quad\blacksquare$

Do you think this is correct?

Answer (score 0):

It’s correct, but I would fill in a few more details, something like this. If $m$ is increasing, for instance, with $m(1)=1$, we know that $m[(0,1]]$ is an interval in $[0,1]$ with righthand endpoint $1$, i.e., either $(a,1]$ or $[a,1]$ for some $a\in[0,1]$. If $a>0$, then clearly $[0,a)$ is an open nbhd of $0$ in $[0,1]$ disjoint from $m[(0,1]]$, which is therefore not dense in $[0,1]$. Thus, we must have $a=0$, and the result follows. (Indeed, you can use the facts that $m^{-1}$ is continuous, continuous maps preserve compactness, $[a,1]$ is compact, and $(0,1]$ is not compact to see that we must have $m[(0,1]]=(0,1]$ in this case.)

The argument in case $m$ is decreasing and $m(1)=0$ is entirely similar.